# Display of data in HTML

Tags: django, django-templates

Suppose I have an object called "comment_list", which is just a list of comments & related info. I'd like to display that to the page, so I do this:

page.html

```
{% for comment in comment_list %}
    <b>ID:{{ comment.id }} - {{ comment.name }} (on {{ comment.submit_date }})</b><br>
    <h4>{{ comment.comment }}</h4><br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

I used the django-comments add-on for this, and it works very well, no problem at all. Now, here's the thing - I wanted to add a special feature to the comments so that if activated, this special feature will display in place of that particular comment. I built a new table that connected to Comments, and linked it via comment_id.

What I then want to do is implement an "if-else" thing in the HTML to replace the comment as it loops. Just to be clear, "comment_list" has multiple objects within. So...:

page.html

```
{% if special_feature.comment_id = comment.id %}
    <b>ID:{{ comment.id }} (on {{ comment.submit_date }})</b><br>
    <h4>YES SPECIAL FEATURE!</h4><br><br>
{% else %}
    <b>ID:{{ comment.id }} - {{ comment.name }} (on {{ comment.submit_date }})</b><br>
    <h4>{{ comment.comment }}</h4><br><br>
{% endif %}
```

"special_feature" also has multiple objects within. But I can't seem to make it work. "special_feature.comment_id" will not appear, because I expect it to have more than one objects inside. I have to specifically state it as "special_feature.X.comment_id", where "X" is a number.

So the solution is to somehow use the "forloop.counter" for that. In which case, the final code could look like so:

page.html

```
{% for comment in comment_list %}
    {% if special_feature.(forloop.counter|add:"-1").comment_id = comment.id %}
        <b>ID:{{ comment.id }} (on {{ comment.submit_date }})</b><br>
        <h4>YES SPECIAL FEATURE!</h4><br><br>
    {% else %}
        <b>ID:{{ comment.id }} - {{ comment.name }} (on {{ comment.submit_date }})</b><br>
        <h4>{{ comment.comment }}</h4><br><br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

"add:-1" is so that the counter starts from "0" rather than "1". "special_feature.(forloop.counter|add:"-1").comment_id" doesn't work obviously, is there a better way to handle this?

EDIT:

Here's the view.py

```
@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def display_comments(request, magazine_slug, art_id):
    context = {}
    populateContext(request, context)

    magazine_data = get_object_or_404(Magazine, slug=magazine_slug)

    article_data = get_object_or_404(Article, project_id=magazine_data.id, id=art_id)

    special_feature = CommentSpecial.objects.all().filter(user_id=request.user.id)

    context = {'article':article_data, 'magazine':magazine_data, 'special_feature':special_feature}



    return render(request, 'projsapp/page.html', context)


@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def add_special_feature_comments(request, art_id):
    context = {}
    populateContext(request, context)

    # Acquire data from post
    data = request.POST
    special_type = data.get('id_special')
    date_time=datetime.datetime.now()

    # Confirm whether article exists
    article_data = get_object_or_404(Article, id=art_id)

    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(article_data)

    # Save a new comment manually
    save_comment=Comment.objects.create(object_pk=art_id, user_name="SYSTEM", user_email="lala@lala.com", comment="SPECIAL", ip_address="127.0.0.1", is_public=1, is_removed=0, content_type_id=content_type.id, site_id=settings.SITE_ID, user_id=request.user.id, submit_date=date_time)

    # Save to CommentSpecial as well!
    CommentSpecial.objects.create(special_type=0, user_id=request.user.id, text="SUPER", comment_id=save_comment.id)


    return HttpResponseR blah blah....
```

And here's model.py for CommentSpecial:

```
class CommentSpecial(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    special_type = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # False = Super Special, True = Typical Special
```

Comment: You use "="-assignment operator in if-statements, but shouldn't you use "=="-operator to compare the values?

Comment: `special_feature.(forloop.counter|add:"-1").comment_id`. That is not valid template syntax. Can you post the view code that generates these context variables?

Comment: I've added the view & models.py.


I'm not very good at rebuilding addons, which is why I tacked on the new table. So when the user clicks a button, it will save an entry to the new table, along with the comment.id value. When displaying, it will read from both the Comment table, and the CommentSpecial table. If it encounters a match, it will show from CommentSpecial, else it will show from Comment instead..... if that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks @MMakela , I tried both, and they both appear to work. However my problem is elsewhere.